# Installing OpenCV in Linux Mint Qiana, Cmake error

Tags: linux, opencv, installation, cmake

I was installing OpenCV on my Linux Mint Qiana system using [this article](https://elementztechblog.wordpress.com/2014/07/28/installing-opencv-2-4-9-in-linux/).

So I downloaded OpenCv-3.0.0-beta from the official OpenCV website and followed the instructions.

I keep getting the error:

```
 CMake Error: The source directory "/home/himanshi" does not appear to
 contain CMakeLists.txt. Specify --help for usage, or press the help
 button on the CMake
```

On typing this:

```
cmake -D WITH_TBB=ON -D BUILD_NEW_PYTHON_SUPPORT=ON -D WITH_V4L=ON -D INSTALL_C_EXAMPLES=ON -D INSTALL_PYTHON_EXAMPLES=ON -D BUILD_EXAMPLES=ON -D WITH_IPP=OFF -D CMAKE_INSTALL_PREFIX=/usr ..
```

What do I do now?

Comment: I recommend you to read this one instead http://docs.opencv.org/doc/tutorials/introduction/linux_install/linux_install.html#linux-installation

Answer (score 0):

The `..` at the end of your call tells CMake to look for the source code and especially the CMakeLists.txt which contains the configure instructions. You have to go to the directory where you have put the OpenCV files, create a build directory there, step into that directory and repeat the command. Than `..` matches your source directory.